# Django model naming conventions

Tags: python, django, django-models, naming-conventions

I have a pretty *stupid* question about model naming conventions in Django.

Imagine a farmstead which has buildings which have rooms.

Farmstead --> Buildings --> Rooms

With Farmstead it is ok, let's call it a `Farmstead`. Next one: `Building` or `FarmsteadBuilding`? `BuildingRoom`, `Room` or `FarmsteadBuildingRoom`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all your instances of `Room` belongs to a `Building` (and there is no another kind of models like `Apartment`) and all your instances of `Building` belongs to a `Farmstead` (following the same idea), so just use the name of your models like `Farmstead`, `Building` and `Room`. It's not necessary to specify something that is already specified in your business logic.

Comment: Then another similar question: if I create a generic app, can I name models like `Article` and `Category` in which the article is in. Or do I need to name it `ArticleCategory`?

Comment: I prefer just `Category` in most cases. If you are creating a `blog` app, for example, `Category` and `Article` are models from a blog. If you have another kind of `Category`, maybe that logic might to be part of another app, not blog. So in this case, you can simple use `from blog import Category` and `from anotherapp import Category as AnotherAppCategory` if you are importing both in the same python module. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of other parts of your code, you could use the name of the Django app, a package, or a module to further scope the names.